# How do I create an Array of objects from a comma separated string field in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have three documents that looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('61e1312ad435c7124aa883a1')
name: "Brian"
languages: "English,Spanish,French"

_id: ObjectId('52e1312ad435c7124aa883a2')
name: "Max"
languages: "English"

_id: ObjectId('37e1312ad435c7124aa883a9')
name: "Mike"
languages: ""
```

As you can see, the **languages** field can either be empty, have one item, or multiple items separated by commas.

I want to create a new field, that is an Array of objects. Each object should consist of a "name" property and an "active" boolean. "name" should be the language and "active" should just be set to false. The end result should look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('61e1312ad435c7124aa883a1')
name: "Brian"
languages: "English,Spanish,French"
newLanguages: [
    { name: "English", active: false },
    { name: "Spanish", active: false },
    { name: "French", active: false }
]

_id: ObjectId('52e1312ad435c7124aa883a2')
name: "Max"
languages: "English,Spanish,French"
newLanguages: [
    { name: "English", active: false }
]

_id: ObjectId('37e1312ad435c7124aa883a9')
name: "Mike"
languages: ""
newLanguages: []
```

I've managed to turn the comma-separated strings into the objects I want, but it doesn't create a new property, it just overwrites the languages property:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      languages: {
        $filter: {
          input: {$split: ["$languages", ","]},
          cond: {$gt: [{$strLenCP: "$$this"}, 0]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      languages: {
        $map: {
          input: "$languages",
          as: "item",
          in: {name: "$$item", active: false}
        }
      }
    }
 }
])
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9v_B-daEQzQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set a new key `newLanguages`, instead of the existing key `languages`, which will stay as it was:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      newLanguages: {
        $filter: {
          input: {$split: ["$languages", ","]},
          cond: {$gt: [{$strLenCP: "$$this"}, 0]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      newLanguages: {
        $map: {
          input: "$newLanguages",
          as: "item",
          in: {name: "$$item", active: false}
        }
      }
    }
 }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9v_B-daEQzQ)